# typoscript negate conditions IP / if - if - else

Tags: typo3, conditional-statements, typoscript

is it possible to negate a condition with typoscript?

We have a page where parts are only seen, if your ip-address is in the range `10.*.*.*`:

```
[IP=10.*.*.*]
  # show internal content
[global]
```

This works. But now we have following problem. The new loadbalancer (waf) has an iternal address, too (i.e. `10.1.2.3`), so the internal content is shown with the above condition!
Unfortunately a negation of the IP-Condition doesn't work. I tried:

```
[IP=10.*.*.*] && [IP!=10.1.2.3]
```

A working solution for negating a condition is:

```
[IP=10.1.2.3]
  # do nothing
[ELSE]
  # show internal content
[global]
```

but I need the condition `[IP=10.*.*.*]` too!
I also tried

```
[IP=10.1.2.3]
  # do nothing
[IP=10.*.*.*]
  # show internal content
[global]
```

but it doesn't work, too.

Maybe someone has an idea to fix it! Changing the loadbalancer-ip is no option!

Thanks,
mph

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is not changing your condition but marking this IP as Reverse Proxy like:

> $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['reverseProxyIP'] = '10.1.2.3';
>   $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue'] = 'last';

This doesn't use your loadbalancer's IP but the original IP used to connect to it. So your condition will work as it used to (provided your loadbalancer sets a proper `X-Forwarded-For` header).

You want to do this because this fixes your issue not only for these conditions but also for logging (TYPO3 sys_log for login-attempts), for IP-Auth etc. so it's the proper way to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way with pure TypoScript:

TS constants:

```
[IP=10.1.2.3]
[else]
  temp.noWaf = 1
[end]
```

TS setup:

```
[IP = 10.*.*.*] && [globalVar = LIT:1 = {$temp.noWaf}]
  # show internal content
[end]
```

However splitting the logic into TS constants and setup is IMHO confusing. Using `globalVar = LIT` is hard to read.

Finaly, some of my attempts to clean things up failed, e.g. using `LIT:0` or `!= LIT:1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [userFunc](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#userfunc) . To retrieve the IP-address you can use `GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('REMOTE_ADDR')` and to compare IP addresses there is `GeneralUtility::cmpIP()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I already implemented an userFuntion php-script which checks the ip - and it's working! I included it in LocalConfiguration.php via `include_once("myuserfuncfile.php")`. I think, this is not the official way - can you explain me, where I should save and include this file? I'm using typo3 6.2.

Comment: Don't use LocalConfiguration.php as this file will be rewritten completely with every change to installed extensions and Install Tool settings.
Best practise is to create an extension to store all configuration, templates, etcetera -- a "site package". That way you could simply refer to the class and function name in the userFunc.
The documentation I linked to suggests to put it in AdditionalConfiguration.php (also in the typo3conf directory).

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the AdditionalConfiguration.php now - works perfect!

Comment: Hi Jigal, maybe you can answer me following question:
I have defined a fe-usergroup "intranet" which also uses the ip-filter (10.*.*.*). Can I use my new defined userfunc as filter?

Answer (score -1):

Basic answer to your question in the topic: Yes, this is possible, and I did it already, here an example:

```
[browser = msie] && [version =  <7] && [globalVar = TSFE:id != 100]
```

(answer friendly taken from pi-phi spicker, http://www.pi-phi.de/19.html)

Comment: globalVar does not support string (ip addresses), but float/integer.

Comment: @stmllr that's not the complete truth. There is:

Comment: arghl ... comments not editable;enter submits form ... schtäkowerflo ...

Comment: So first, there ist globalVar LIT, which basically supports literals.
secondly there is globalString which does pretty much the same like globalvar, but for strings.
globalString also supports PCRE style regular expressions.
with all this information added, it should be not that hard to do a typoscript solution for the described problem.

More information:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#globalstring

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#id44